# Is it possible to write a method in Scala returning objects with different type parameter?

Tags: scala, type-parameter

Is it possible to write a method in Scala which returns an object of a type-parameterized class with different type paramter ? Something like this:

```
class A[T]

def f(switch: Boolean): A = if(switch) new A[Int] else new A[String]
```

Please note: The Code above is fictional to show the type of problem; The code above does not make semantically sense.

The code above will not compile because return type A is not parameterized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, and you can even do it with type-safety with the aid of implicit arguments that encapsulate the pairings:

```
class TypeMapping[+A,B] {
  def newListB = List.empty[B]
}
trait Logical
object True extends Logical
object False extends Logical

implicit val mapFalseToInt = new TypeMapping[False.type,Int]
implicit val mapTrueToString = new TypeMapping[True.type,String]

def f[A <: Logical,B](switch: A)(implicit tmap: TypeMapping[A,B]) = tmap.newListB

scala> f(True)
res2: List[String] = List()

scala> f(False)
res3: List[Int] = List()
```

You do have to explicitly map from boolean values to the custom `True` and `False` values.

(I have chosen `List` as the target class just as an example; you could pick anything or even make it generic with a little more work.)

(Edit: as oxbow_lakes points out, if you need all possible return values to be represented on the same code path, then this alone won't do it, because the superclass of `List[Int]` and `List[String]` is `List[Any]`, which isn't much help.  In that case, you should use an `Either`.  My solution is for a single function that will be used only in the `True` or `False` contexts, and can maintain the type information there.)

Comment: Very interesting; do you use this sort of thing in practice (as it's a lot of boilerplate)? I'd almost argue that the *mechanics* required to get this sort of thing to work are a useful pointer that there is a design deficit at the heart of it.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - Actually, yes, I do use this in practice, though only rarely, when it is very important that I keep my types straight in this way.

Comment: It almost seems like it would have been easier to have 2 methods: `fInt` and `fString` (at least in this simplified example!)

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - Indeed, it usually is, which is why I use this rarely.  Actually, I've never used it in _exactly_ this form; there's always something more complicated going on.  For example, in one case I had a set of not-entirely-trivial type selection rules, and rather than propagating a half dozen different function names through three or four layers of nesting, it was easier to set up a framework like this.

Comment: @RexKerr Thank you for this working example. By reading your post, I had a feeling, that it is not intented to do something I wanted in Scala ? I see your workaround works, but Scala itself does not provide to do it in a direct way ?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood - Scala doesn't give you much help for doing things in a type-unsafe manner, and it provides general mechanisms like the one I've shown above to do it with type-safety.  See oxbow_lakes' answer for an alternative method for keeping multiple return options straight.

Answer (score 4):

One way of expressing this would be by using `Either`;

```
def f(switch: Boolean) = if (switch) Left(new A[Int]) else Right(newA[String])
```

This of course returns an `Either[A[Int], A[String]]`. You certainly cannot (at the moment) declare a method which returns some parameterized type `P`, with some subset of type parameters (i.e. *only* `Int` *or* `String`).

The language **ceylon** has union types and I understand the intention is to add these to scala in the near future, in which case, you *could* define a method:

```
def f(switch: Boolean): A[Int|String] = ...
```

Comment: Thank your for your example code. I did not know the Left/Right statements before. Although this solution is a workaround, the used feature looks interesting to me.

Comment: Is there another class/feature, like Either, which can take more alternatives (writing Either[Either[..], Either[..]] looks a bit ugly) ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like that.

```
scala> class A {
     |   type T
     | }
defined class A

scala> def f(b: Boolean): A = if(b) new A { type T = Int } else new A { type T = String }
f: (b: Boolean)A
```

But this is pointless. Types are a compile time information, and that information is getting lost here.

Comment: As Rex's answer demonstrates, if you use a type-level boolean, the information wouldn't be lost.

Answer (score -1):

How about an absolutely minimal change to the "fictional code"? If we just add `[_]` after the "fictional" return type, the code will compile:

```
class A[T]
def f(switch: Boolean):A[_] = if(switch) new A[Int] else new A[String]
```

It is worth noting that `A[_]` is not the same as `A[Any]`. `A[T]` does not need to be defined covariant for the code to compile.
Unfortunately, information about the type gets lost.

Comment: This evaluates only to `Any` and not to `A`.

Comment: This wouldn't work at all; you have just defined a type-parameter which happens to be called `List`

Comment: Oops, it was meant to be a return type, not type parameter. Fixed now!